# Flutter DialogFlow without answer on Production Playstore App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, dialogflow-es

I've created a app on Google Play, and the first version works fine but I made recently a new version (5.0) and I was testing this version before to upload on Google Play, and everything was fine: - Android physicall device debug was working ok 100%. - Android virtual device debug was working ok 100%, - DialogFlow Essentials Console was working ok 100%. Finally after the update I have an app without answers. I attatch images for better explanation. I would very much appreciate your answer.

- This is the Google Play App:
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DiegoBermudez.LicenciadoMexicano

  [android virtual device debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mit7q.png)
  [DialogFlow Essentials Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNgz9.png)
  [android physicall device debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLbnx.jpg)
  [android Google Play app testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Q8n.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add internet permission in android manifest

Comment: You may be correct, your comment made me detect that I needed the permissions. Google Play takes approximately 2 business days to update the new app. Until then I confirm that it has been solved, for the moment very good observation and thank you!

Comment: Glad that it was helpful. Please accept my answer if it was useful. Also before uploading to play store just to be sure build a signed apk in release mode using `flutter build apk` for a final round of testing.